# deserialize nested arbitrary class in java with gson

Tags: java, json, arraylist, gson, nested-class

i need to convert the json-string **tmp** =>
**{"result_count":1,"next_offset":1,"entry_list":[{"id":"xyz123","module_name":"Products","name_value_list":{"id":{"name":"id","value":"xyz123"},"name":{"name":"name","value":"test_product_2"}}}],"relationship_list":[]}** 
into a corresponding java-pojo

my pojo looks like

```
public class GetEntryListResponse {

public int result_count = 0;
public int next_offset = 0;
public List<EntryList> entryList = new ArrayList<EntryList>();
public static class EntryList {
    String id = "";
    String module_name = "";
    public static class NameValueList {
        public static class Id {
            String name = "";
            String value = "";
        }
        public static class Name {
            String name = "";
            String value = "";
        }
    }
}
}
```

and for the deserilizing-task a use

```
Gson json_response = new Gson();
GetEntryListResponse resp = json_response.fromJson(tmp, 
                                                   GetEntryListResponse.class);
```

i also tried other variants but this one seems to be the best so far. the problem is that result_count and next_offset are transformed into int but the type of the array entryList is  with null-values.

Comment: You're mixing styles: `result_count` and `entryList` can together make no good (unless you employ the same chaos in Json). I can't see you using any `FieldNamingStrategy` so I wonder how can it work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Implement InstanceCreator and JsonDeserializer for your class

```
  public class GetEntryListResponse implements
            InstanceCreator<GetEntryListResponse>,
            JsonDeserializer<GetEntryListResponse>{

    @Override
        public GetEntryListResponse createInstance(Type type) {
            return this;
        }

    @Override
        public GetEntryListResponse deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT){
      json.getJsonObject();// 
    // create your classes objects here by json key
    }
```

and use

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.registerTypeAdapter(GetEntryListResponse.class,
                new GetEntryListResponse()).create();
```

Comment: This makes no sense. I can't see any problem with instance creation here, nor any need for custom deserialization. And I don't understand why a class should be used as `InstanceCreator` and/or `JsonDeserializer` for itself (isn't it a bad style?).

Comment: as mentioned in the second post changing **entryList** to **entry_list** worked. but in my opinion your suggestion is the preferred one. if i ran into this again in think i will use a custom deserializer as @yahor10 mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

try changing:

```
public List<EntryList> entryList = new ArrayList<EntryList>();
```

to:

```
public List<EntryList> entry_list= new ArrayList<EntryList>();
```

and deserialize.

Comment: changing **entryList** to **entry_list** somehow did the trick. i also changed the class structure from static classes to an instance based one. still don't understand why this works because according to the gson user guide arbitrary classes should be used in a static way [RawCollectionsExample](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/extras/examples/rawcollections/RawCollectionsExample.java)